# Array if statements and printing the array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` that I would like to store objects in (strings). I have an account constructor (int, string, string) built, but am not sure if I am populating the arraylist with its values correctly:

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
list.add(Account);
```

also, once I get this array to populate correctly, I'd like to be able to print values using if statements or whatever is best.

so if each item in the array is in `int`, str1, str2 format, if the int=1 system.print "yellow", if str1 is "b", system.print "ice", and if str2 is "c", system.print "green"

Comment: You would like to store strings in the ArrayList, but you're adding an account? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: What exactly is `Account`? Is it a class? You also mention an array in your text, but I don't see one in your code.

Comment: The question is a little confusing, apart from the fact that this object is of type Account. It doesn't say what to do if all the fields match the condition? Should they be appended? or First match should be taken and at most only one word should be printed. Also, if any of the answer solves your problem, kindly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always a good idea to define your collections with the narrowest type you can. In this case your `ArrayList` should be defined as a collection of `Account` objects rather than a collection of `Object`.

For example:

```
List<Account> allAccounts = new ArrayList<>();
allAccounts.add(new Account(1, "a", "x"));
allAccounts.add(new Account(2, "b", "y"));
allAccounts.add(new Account(3, "c", "z"));
```

To iterate through the accounts you can use this syntax:

```
for (Account account : allAccounts) {
    if (account.id() == 1) {
        System.out.println("yellow");
    }       
    if ("b".equals(account.name())) {
        System.out.println("ice");
    }       
    if ("c".equals(account.description())) {
        System.out.println("green");
    }       
}
```

All this assumes you have an Account class that looks something like this:

```
public class Account {
    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    private final String description;

    public Account(int id, String name, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int id() {
        return id;
    }

    public String name() {
        return name;
    }

    public String description() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding,

The `Account` instance has field variables which has an integer field, and two string fields

```
    //Use a List of Account instead of List of Object 
    List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>()
    //Add the account objects you need
    accounts.add(new Account(1 , "str1" , "str2"))
    for(Account account : accounts){
        if(account.int1 == 1){
            System.out.println("Yellow");
        }
        if(account.str1.equals("b")){
            System.out.println("ice");
        }
        if(account.str2.equals("c")){
            System.out.println("green");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to aetheria's answer, if what should be printed is a logic of the Account object itself, you can consider overriding the `toString` method.

Something like:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s%s%s", (this.id == 1 ? "Yellow " : ""), (this.name.equals("a") ? "Ice " : ""), (this.description.equals("b") ? "Green" : ""));
}
```

If you do this, then you can simply do:

```
for (Account account : accounts) {
    System.out.println(account);
}
```

or `System.out.println(accounts);`